# Can I use a bitmap instead of a data source for a WPF chart?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, bitmap, wpftoolkit

I can draw an empty set of axes, and have some complex code to create a bitmap from my input data. What I'd like to do is use the axes but overlay my bitmap.

The graph I'm creating contains a possible 20,951,040 data points, so drawing the graph to a texture is the quickest way to achieve what I want, and takes a matter of milliseconds to render so I'm happy with the bitmap - just need it to be placed in axes to give some context obviously.